# Linux Regex snake case to camel case with word matchinf

Tags: json, shell, sed

I am stuck on a problem where we need to convert snake case to camel case inside a json key. This all has to happen in linux shell script
The json is as below

```
[{“name”:”THE_NAME1”,”value”:”Value_1”}, {“name”:”THE_NAME_NEW2”,”value”:”Value_2”}]
```

The expected output from regex

```
[{“name”:”theName1”,”value”:”Value_1”}, {“name”:”theNameNew2”,”value”:”Value_2”}]
```

The values should not change.

Comment: Those aren't double-quotes (`"`). Is that really what your data contains?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jq` to manipulate the appropriate values:

```
jq '
   map(
      .name |= (
         ascii_downcase |
         gsub(
            "_(?<a>[a-z])";
            .a|ascii_upcase
         )
      )       
   )
' <json
```

- [map](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/docs/content/manual/v1.6/manual.yml#L816)(*filter*) - apply filter to each element of array
- *path*[`|=`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/docs/content/manual/v1.6/manual.yml#L3010)(*filter1*|*filter2*|...) - update *path* by applying filters
- *filter1*[`|`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/docs/content/manual/v1.6/manual.yml#L467)*filter2* - chain filters
- [`ascii_downcase`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/docs/content/manual/v1.6/manual.yml#L1568) - convert A..Z to a..z
- [`gsub`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/docs/content/manual/v1.6/manual.yml#L2372)(*regex*; *string*) - replace all occurrences of *regex* by *string* after interpolation of capture variables
- [`ascii_upcase`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/docs/content/manual/v1.6/manual.yml#L1568) - convert a..z to A..Z

Comment: `.a` instead of `"\(.a)"` ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.